# Specify a time to users in multiple time zones (especially USA/Canada)

Tags: datetime, user-interface, time, timezone

I'm implementing a sign up facility which sends a link with a token in it - the token is valid for 1 hour. So in the email (let's say it is 14:20 now) I want to say:

*You must click this link by 15:30*

The audience for this site will be in Ireland / UK, USA / Canada and perhaps some in Europe - so I wanted to list the expiry time in several time zones that these (non technical) people will understand.

So this is what I came up with

```
Click by:

Ireland/UK > 25 Apr 2018 13:59
CET (Berlin) > 25 Apr 2018 14:59

Pacific (Los Angeles) > 25 Apr 2018 05:59

Mountain (Denver) > 25 Apr 2018 06:59

Central (Chicago) > 25 Apr 2018 07:59

Eastern (New York) > 25 Apr 2018 08:59
```

Now, I understand that Denver is currently MDT (and MST in the winter), but here in Ireland, we are now in IST (UTC + 1) or GMT in the winter/fall - but if you ask a random person what timezone are we in, at best you will get GMT as a response all year round. So, I list the time there as a generic 'Mountain' and give a sample city.

How is this approach for people in USA / Canada?

My code is below and here is a  [live link](http://solomon.ie/time.php)

```
<?php
$exipry = 60*60 + time();

$now_obj       = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $exipry));

$now_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Dublin'));
$now_hour_from_IRELAND_datetime = $now_obj->format('d M Y H:i');


$now_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$now_hour_from_CET_datetime = $now_obj->format('d M Y H:i');

$now_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$now_hour_from_pacific_datetime = $now_obj->format('d M Y H:i');

$now_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
$now_hour_from_mountain_datetime = $now_obj->format('d M Y H:i');

$now_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
$now_hour_from_central_datetime = $now_obj->format('d M Y H:i');

$now_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$now_hour_from_eastern_datetime = $now_obj->format('d M Y H:i');

print("<h1>1 hour from now is:</h1>");
print("Ireland/UK  > $now_hour_from_IRELAND_datetime<p>");
print("CET (Berlin) > $now_hour_from_CET_datetime<p>");
print("Pacific (Los Angeles) > $now_hour_from_pacific_datetime<p>");
print("Mountain (Denver) > $now_hour_from_mountain_datetime<p>");
print("Central (Chicago) > $now_hour_from_central_datetime<p>");
print("Eastern (New York) > $now_hour_from_eastern_datetime<p>");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks will do. But I was m ore interested in the UI side of things, like how familiar are North Americans with timezones and is my text clear?

Comment: Can you clarify your question: Are you just wanting to know which time zones should be in your list to cover the United States and Canada?  Or did you want others as well?  Please be specific.  Thanks.

Comment: See my comment below O Jones' answer - just need this for USA customers, more likely on East coast. Trying to present the link expiry time in as simple as possible language without complicating things be saying DST or not if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct to me.

Be sure to test it for 'Asia/Kolkata' too. That's a good test because its time zone offset is on a half-hour.

Ditto for 'America/Phoenix' because they stay on standard time all year.

Usually apps like this ask each user to provide a timezone name during onboarding. (But many users don't bother)

In the US when we want to specify a timezone in a way where it doesn't have to change between summer and winter, we say "Eastern Time", "Central Time", "Mountain Time", "Pacific Time," and Hawaii and Alaska time. The Canadians also have "Atlantic Time" ('America/Halifax'). In Arizona ('America/Phoenix') they say 'Arizona Time'.

Comment: I could go on about all the time zone wierdness in the US state of Indiana (where the legislature once came close to passing a law establishing the value of π as 22/7). But I will spare you.

Comment: Just tried India, worked ok. Actually, I did have Phoenix for Mountain time and thought I had  a bug as was same as LA. Looked further to see they have no DST. Ah, we all know pie is 3 and a slice!

Comment: I updated the live link with suggested text. Unless you think I need to, I'll leave it at 4 timezones as in reality, this site is about Irish products, I'd say the further away from the East coast, the less interest.

Comment: Everybody in the US is Irish on St. Patrick's Day. But that day is always during daylight savings time.